# turn off the onclick during the function runnig

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, onclick

I want to turn off the onclick till the function that was called by the onclick is done. How can I do that? But I don't want to turn off the onclick forever

```
    function move() {

   //do things...

$("#carr").off("click");
    }



    dado.onclick = move;
```

Comment: As soon as the element is clicked, invoke the function and disable the element. When the function is complete, enable the element.

Answer (score 0):

While you can add and remove eventListeners, it might be a better idea to add a guard for the function invocation, e.g.

```
var isRunning = false;

function myFunction(e, cb) {
  // do stuff
  return cb();
}

function guard(functionToRun, e) {
  if (isRunning) {
    return;
  }
  isRunning = true;
  functionToRun(e, function() {
    isRunning = false;
  });
}

$someNode.on('click', guard.bind(this, myFunction));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Use JQuery's bind and unbind functions:

```
function move() {
    $("#carr").unbind("click");

    //do stuff

    $("#carr").bind("click", function () {
        move();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
        move();
});
```